# how can I pass my variable into Default Content in emailext jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm using script pipeline to send email, and would like to use DEFAULT CONTENT for email body.
my script

```
    def mailRecipients = "user@mydomain.com"
    def result = '1234567'
    emailext (
        subject: "${buildStatus}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
        body: '${DEFAULT_CONTENT}',
        //recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],[$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
        mimeType: 'text/html',to: "${mailRecipients}"
```

my body is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEBVv.png)

how can i pass variable result from pipeline to default content email body

Comment: your question is not clear what you need please explain in simple words

Comment: did you see my picture, how can I pass variable result = '1234567' into default content , in my content I use ${result} but it cannot show 1234567

Comment: ok so you want to send the whatever result value will be added to body right?

Comment: yes, and must using  default content, I don't want using text/html format in script